# How to make a "normal" program shortcut in the installer?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, shortcut-file

I have a problem with the shortcuts generated by our current Wix setup - when a user right-clicks the desktop icon and pins it to the taskbar, that taskbar icon is lost when they upgrade to the next version. I presume it's because the old shortcut is invalidated and a new one replaces it, rendering the pinned one obsolete.

The shortcuts don't have the usual filename and path in the Target field, just the application name grayed out. I thought this was due to using an advertised shortcut, but I changed it to `Advertise="no"` and added `Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]MyApp.exe"` but the shortcut properties didn't change. My theory is that if the shortcut referenced the actual file, it would still be valid after the upgrade as long as the application didn't change its location or name.

So, question 1: is it possible to make a shortcut that contains the full pathname to the application?

Question 2: if it's possible, is it a good idea? Are there installer capabilities that we'd be sabotaging by doing this, or other bad side effects?

Question 3: is there a better way to solve the problem that I'm not considering?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="MyAppComponents">

      <Component Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Guid="*">
        <File KeyPath="yes" Source="MyApp.exe">
          <Shortcut Id="MyAppShortcut" Name="MyApp" Directory="ShortcutFolder" Icon="Product.exe" Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]MyApp.exe" Advertise="no" />
          <Shortcut Id="DesktopShortcut" Name="MyApp" Directory="DesktopFolder" Icon="Product.exe" Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]MyApp.exe" Advertise="no" />
        </File>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the [WorkingDirectory attribute](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_shortcut.htm) of the shortcut element? I had the same problem, and if I recall correctly, that solved the problem for me.

```
<Shortcut Id="MyAppShortcut" Name="MyApp" Directory="ShortcutFolder" Icon="Product.exe" Target="MyApp.exe" Advertise="no" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" />
<Shortcut Id="DesktopShortcut" Name="MyApp" Directory="DesktopFolder" Icon="Product.exe" Target="MyApp.exe" Advertise="no" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" />
```

Try it like that. I'm pretty sure the shortcut's target is actually the working directory + the target file, but I haven't touched this stuff in a while.

Comment: Sorry, this didn't help. I appreciate the response though.

Comment: @MarkRansom Try removing the brackets in the WorkingDirectory attribute. I just checked and that might be it.